# How to create a cron job on a Google Compute Engine instance via a PHP App Engine application?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cron, google-compute-engine

Due to the architecture of our App Engine application we can't use the App Engine cron service that Google provides and are looking for alternative options.

One possible solution we have come up with is to allow our App Engine PHP application to automatically create a cronjob on a compute engine instance. This instance would simply be a utility machine which would handle nothing but the cron jobs.

How would we create the crons in compute engine from within the App Engine application using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your google cloud instances can go down or up at any minute, (And also, you may have multiple instances of the same app running), which would make cron unreliable as it may trigger multiple times across multiple machines, google has created Task Scheduling, which is available on Google Compute Engine.

A great tutorial can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine), and a sample can be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine-sample).

For a PHP specific implementation of pub/sub, see [this link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/pubsub/app).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did look at this option, but the issue we have is that our Google App Engine application runs under multiple sub-domains e.g. clientA.example.com, clientB.example.com, and each subdomain will have it's own set of cron requirements. The Task Scheduling option seems to still require an App Engine cron to get things going, but this would mean we'd need to have a global cron script that would run for all sub-domains, which is not ideal if we have a lot of clients.

Comment: One global cron that fires off specific processes for each client should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use PHP, but it may help the reader to know you can just do

`sudo crontab -e`

on an Ubuntu 16 *GCloud Compute Engine* instance like on a normal Linux box