# discord.js bot goes offline after terminal being closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, ubuntu-20.04

I’ve been having this issue with my discord bot for a while where it just goes offline even though the process is still running.

I’ve tried using `nohup node index.js &` then `disown -a` and finally `exit`, but the bot still dies.

Note that it doesn’t die INSTANTLY, but about 30 minutes to an hour after I close my terminal, and there’s no error message in `nohup.out`. But when I use `top`, the process still running.

I’m on Ubuntu-20.04 using Google Cloud Service VM, discord.js 13.6.0, Node.js v17.9.0

And my code looks like this:

`index.js`

```js
const discord = require(“discord.js”);

const allIntents = new discord.Intents(32767);
const client = new discord.Client({intents: [allIntents]});

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

require(“dotenv”).config();

client.on(“ready”, async () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setStatus(“idle”);
    createSlashCommands(client);
    
    var stats = [“hi”, “hello”];
    const length = stats.length;
    for (let i = 0, true, i = (i+1)%length) {
         client.user.setActivity(stats[i], {type: 3});
         await sleep(10000);
    }
});

message.on(“messageCreate”, async (message) => {
    if (client.isReady() && !message.author.bot) {
        if (message.content === “t!ping”) {
            message.reply({content: `Pong! ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms`});
        }
    }
});

client.on(“interactionCreate”, async (interaction) => {
    if (client.isReady() && !message.author.bot) {
        if (interaction.commandName === “ping”) {
            interaction.reply({content: `Pong! ${Date.now() - interaction.createdTimestamp}ms`});
        }
    }
});

client.login(process.env.mybot);
```

Is there any other way I can prevent my bot from going offline? Or is there something I did wrong?

Comment: `nohup`  redirect standard output and ignore the hangup signal, it may not be best fit to controll terminal from being closed after script execution, could you try `pm2`? as it would be better to monitor on the process level for log and error

Comment: It turned out using pm2 still died, and still nothing was shown in the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution that I have found and use (and it is free) is pm2

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/

```
npm i pm2 -g

// navigate to the folder with your main bot.js file (in this example it is called index.js)

pm2 start index.js

// followed by

pm2 save

// Optionally you can monitor the whole server as well with

pm2-server-monit
```

Comes with a free dashboard as well

As for your code, I would make a couple changes

```js
// change:
client.on(“ready”, async () => {

// to:
client.once("ready", async () => {
```

Also, these won't really ever be needed because if the client isn't ready, it won't capture the event

scratch this everywhere

```js
client.isReady() &&
```

```js
// Lastly, this needs to be 
client.on("messageCreate"
 
// rather than
message.on("messageCreate"
```

EDIT:
Do not leave the debug active in the code all the time unless you just want to.
Place this in your code like shown

```js
// prev code
require(“dotenv”).config();

// Error Logging
client.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
})
client.on('warn', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
})
// comment the below one out when not using it to debug
client.on('debug', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
})
process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) => {
    console.log('Unhandled promise rejection:', error)
})

client.once(“ready”, async () => {
// code following
```

Comment: Had to edit that a few times sorry, kept needing to add a thing here and there

Comment: using pm2 didn’t work for me. bot still went offline, but pm2 says it’s running, and nothing was shown in the logs.

Comment: Did you make the code changes as well?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a bit of code to do some debugging, try that out and then paste the console log in a pastebin and provide a link so we can see whats going on

Comment: Oh yeah, uh, the message.on was a dumb typo, it's client.on in my actual code. But may I ask what is the difference between client.on and client.once? Also I've just added client.on debug to my code, lemme wait it until it dies again

Comment: `client.once` triggers the event only once. The first time the event happens and ignores all other events that match, `client.on` triggers everytime the event happens. So if discord tells the bot to reconnect to refresh its connection, then it will become ready again, even though it never really went offline, but will re-run the entire "ready" event code again. BTW you have a function `createSlashCommands(client);` that doesn't show to be defined in the code you provided, I assume it is defined elsewhere?

Comment: May also want to take a look at this in the event you have to use it this way rather than through CLI
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/use-pm2-with-cloud-providers/?msclkid=d57cb8d8ba6e11ecab7a60c630cf8e31

Comment: I updated my answer again with other error logging code that may prove helpful

Comment: Hi, yes, createSlashCommands() was defined in my other js file. And I just checked the logs right after my bot died, all it says is just "sending a heartbeat" and "heartbeat acknowledged, latency 190ms". So this didn't work out ;(

Comment: @TataOwO similar issue here may want to check out the top rated answer for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221807/google-cloud-instance-terminate-after-close-browser?msclkid=32e2004dbb4c11ec80082de999b527c1

Comment: Not quite the same issue I have, because my script doesn't stop running. It just somehow doesn't connect to discord anymore and then bot goes offline while the script is still running. But I'll try that out, and I will tell you if it worked, thanks!

Comment: Well, it turned out it still died in the end. I think the problem might be on google's sides and not mine. That could be why we've tried so many ways but none worked out. I guess I'll just change a cloud service then.

Comment: I would be likely to agree with you on that. PM2 has never given me any issues like that